# iOSの基本的な使い方についての質問はここでしても問題ない?

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

### 前置き

Stack Overflowの機能として、ユーザー投票によって質問を「クローズ」したり削除したりすることができるようになっています。他のQ&Aサイトではあまり見ない機能ですが、回答を投稿する人が「回答したい」と思うような質問が集まるサイトとしてのクオリティを保つ効果があります。

どういう質問をオフトピックとしてクローズする（閉じる）のか、逆にいうと私たちはコミュニティ全体としてどういう質問を歓迎するのかについて、今後いつも積極的に話し合っていく必要があります。そうしないと、いつのまにか何故かおもしろみのないサイトになってしまうかもしれません。これは、コンテンツを自治するパワーを与えられているということでもあります。

### 本題

[iOSシミュレータで日本語入力を行うには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/452/ios%E3%82%B7%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A5%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%A7%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E5%85%A5%E5%8A%9B%E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF) は、iOSの使い方についての質問ではないか、という意見が出ていました。

質問を抽象化して、「**プログラマーではないユーザーも行きあたるようなiOSの問題**についての質問」とします。

こういう質問はオフトピックとした方がよいですか?

- プログラマーとして行きあたる可能性がある問題は、他のプログラマーも興味がある問題なのでオントピックでいい
- 基本的な使い方はここで聞かないで他で調べてほしい (オフトピックとする)

などの考え方があると思います。みなさんの考えはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 9):

元質問に回答したものですが、

> - プログラマーとして行きあたる可能性がある問題は、他のプログラマーも興味がある問題なのでオントピックでいい
> - 基本的な使い方はここで聞かないで他で調べてほしい (オフトピックとする)

今回の、日本語入力をするにはどうすればいいのか、という質問自体はiOSを普段使っている人であればすぐに分かることですし、質問としては、ほとんど価値はないのかなとは思います。なので、ググってください、という気持ちはたしかにあります。

ただ、シミュレータの言語環境を切り替えたり、言語環境がデフォルトで日本語になっていなかったりするのは、たしかに市販のiPhoneを普通に使っているだけでは触らない機能もありますし、Macのハードウェアキーボードから入力できたりする、という情報を知らないとクリックで情報入力していくことになってしまったりします。

なので、半々です。

正直線引きが難しいので一つ一つ潰していく感覚で、
基本的に日本語SO内で

- 「その質問は、この質問と重複しています」
- 「その質問は、この回答で解決できるのでは」

と言えるようになるまでは、あまりにもひどいもの以外はオフトピックとして扱わない、という方針でもいいのかなと思っています。

曖昧模糊としていて申し訳ありません。参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。投票数からみて、こちらの路線が支持されているようですね。重複の場合は、「重複として閉じる」機能が使えます。「もう基本的な使い方の質問はみんな興味ないんだよ！」という状態になったら、またメタで議論すればよいかなと思います。

Answer (score 3):

「オフトピック」というより、ちょっとした努力さえしていない質問にたいして「マイナス票」が適切だと思います。マイナス票の矢印をHoverすると、下記のツールチップが出てきます：

> この質問には解決しようと努力した跡が見られない・実用的ではない・分かりにくい

ググったらすぐ回答が探せる質問と思ったら、クローズされるより、マイナス票を投票したら大丈夫どうですか？

Comment: プログラミングの問題なら「今までに何を試したか?」という情報は解決の助けになりますが、「今までにどうやって調べましたか?」というのは聞いてもあまり解決に向けて進まないように思います。マイナス票で「ググるべき」という意志表示をするよりは、回答+ググり方 (キーワード) を投稿すると役に立つと思います。どうでしょう

Answer (score 2):

個人的には、「価値が無い」と断定するのは、主観的な問題だと思います。「くだらない質問」だと思うようなことでも、他の人にとっては「価値がある」質問となることもありうると思います。

「○○していればすぐ分かる」というのは、客観的な根拠はなにもありませんし、分からないからこそ質問しているのだと、僕は思います。

むしろ、僕等が恒日頃から、「当然とした知識」こそ、初学者にとって暗黙知となりやすく、非常に効果があったりするのかもしれません。

また、今回の件で言えば「シミュレータのiOS」と「実機のiOS」は違うものと考えていたりすれば、開発者しか使わないであろう「シミュレータのiOS」の質問のつもりだったのかもしれません。

> 質問を抽象化して、「プログラマーではないユーザーも行きあたるようなiOSの問題についての質問」とします。
>
> こういう質問はオフトピックとした方がよいですか?

との回答ですが、

- プログラマーにとって関係の無い意見であれば閉じるべき

だとは考えます。

Comment: そういえば以前、「ググれば分かる」というクローズ理由を試験的に導入してみた結果、[取り止めになった](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86043/157841) (英語) ということがありました。その[取り止め理由が話題の1つだったポッドキャスト](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/se-podcast-20/)であげられていた、「質問者がググったかは関係ない、役に立つ質問がそこにあれば回答するだけである」という考え方は同感でした。ちなみに、最後の「...関係の無い意見」というのは「質問」ということですか?